# Fire Simulation Hitting Border

Tags: fluid-simulation, fire

Trying to make a torch, but the fire simulation keeps going to the top of the border. How do I shorten the flame?

[image]

Comment: Try reducing the Fuel value of the flow source: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/type/flow.html#settings

Comment: thank you that worked

Comment: You’re welcome. :-) Now comes the question as to whether I copy this comment into an answer… you know what, you copy it: You can answer your own question.